# Why is capistrano interpreting a flag passed with a command to `run` as input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, capistrano

I'm trying to do this:

```
run "echo -n 'foo' > bar.txt"
```

and the contents of bar.txt ends up being:

```
-n foo \n
```

(With `\n` representing an actual newline)

I use run for other commands like `rm -rf` and, to my knowledge, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this in `man echo`:

> Some shells may provide a builtin echo command which is similar or identical to this utility.  Most notably, the builtin echo in sh(1) does not accept the -n option.  Consult the builtin(1) manual page.

My version of bash has an `echo` builtin but seems to be respecting the `-n` flag. It looks like the shell on your deployment machine doesn't, in which case using the full path to the `echo` binary might do what you want here:

```
run "/bin/echo -n 'foo' > bar.txt"
```

Comment: yes! amazing! my bash and zsh both take the -n flag, but I guess not "sh"?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though the -n flag isn't being interpreted as a flag by the shell. If, from the command line, one executes echo -Y hi, the output will be -Y hi.